# For repetitive "SELECT" query, does Linq access databsase each time or it gives you values from its in-memory Entity objects?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

By Linq, I mean Entity Framework and Linq. A further question, if the SELECT query is the same, but OEDER BY clause is different, does Linq have to access the database or the in-memory entities have enough information for the new SELECT query with different ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Write down a sample query to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Aliostad: I mean like when you manually call the DataBind() method of the GridView control whose DataSource is EntityDataSource, you are essentially calling the same SELECT query to populate the GridView, I suspect Linq does not have to access the underlying database

Comment: It's going to hit the DB again, but there is no reason you can't cache your result set to use when rebinding your paging/sorting events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, once the Entity is created, the Entity itself contains all the information that will be used for data binding, unless you explicitly instruct the Entity to requery the underlying data store.